# Android activity page curl animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have to give a page curl animation to my activity transactions. I have checked with Android page curl demo on images but it's not working for activity.

**Here are the links through which we can implement page curl animation on images not on activities:**

https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip

http://devappandroid.com/android-beginner/page-curlturn-effect-android

How could we implement page curl animation in activity.

Comment: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/. check this

Comment: Thanks for replying but i have already checked this.This is suitable for images not for activities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below link for better curl effects,
[Curl Effect Lib](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)
[image]